# Second video card (PCI) under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to get an old PCI video card (Diamond Stealth 2500) along with a normal PCI-E video card.

In BIOS, there is a setting to switch between PEG/PCI or PCI/PEG on startup (PEG is PCI-E Graphics). When I use PCI/PEG only the old PCI card works, when I use the other one, only the new PEG card works.

In PEG/PCI mode, Windows 7 recognizes the card and shows it in Device Manager as Standard VGA adapter, but it shows a warning for the device ("This device cannot start. (Code 10)").

Comment: old is right, this card is 10 years old, i don't think you will get it working with windows 7. i had a similar card and there was no way to get working with Vista.

Comment: @milly7244:  I've used a Matrox PCI gfx card pulled from a p-mmx box under win7.  I suspect it may have been running under an MS generic driver, but it worked as an emergency spare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Vista and WDDM 1.0, the [Windows Vista Display Driver Model (WDDM) doesn't support heterogenous multi-adapter configurations](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/display/multimonVista.mspx). If your primary video card uses the WDDM 1.0 model, then you will not be able to use the Diamond Stealth as a second display even if you can find Windows 7 compatible drivers for it. If your primary video card uses the older XPDM model, then you may be able to get your multi-adapter configuration working, but you won't be able to use Aero Glass. As @prestomation pointed out in the comments, WDDM 1.1 adds support for heterogenous multi-adapter configurations. I doubt that there are any WDDM drivers for a video card of this vintage anyway.

If your primary video card doesn't support two displays, you might want to upgrade to one that does. If it does support two displays and you're trying to add a third, you might be able to add an identical/compatible video card, given a free PCIe slot. There are also a few models of video card that support four displays on one card.

Comment: Thank you, that was a comprehensive answer. The fact that WDDM/XPDM drivers can't be used at the same time is good to know. I'll probably need to get a PCIe x1 card (since that's the only slot I have), or a 4-monitor card.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model#WDDM_1.1
This is incorrect. Win7 now uses WDDM 1.1 which according to Wikipedia can "Support multiple drivers in a multi-adapter, multi-monitor setup".
This doesn't help this particular situation with this card, but wanted to make note of it.

Comment: @prestomation: Thanks for the correction. It's good to hear that MS brought back multi-driver video support in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem here. Worst thing is - the PCI vid card works very well when alone. I was very surprised how 2meg ATI Rage IIC handled graphics under win7. Windows, flash, youtube, movies - all worked without problems (didn't even tried games lol :) no aero too). Unfortunately this thing won't fly with PCIE radeon X800 installed as primary.

Just to rephrase - it's not a problem of a missing driver.

Answer (score 0):

[Code 10 refers (usually) to driver error](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/310123)

I recommend updating the drivers, there may be a problem if one of your cards is Nvidia and the other is ATI as they do not always play nice together.

Comment: The stealth 2500 is before diamond went all ati. This card is over 10 years old.

Comment: well, my thing is just a guess - still best thing is try to find a modern driver, but with the age, perhaps it is time to give up! that being said, without knowing more about this pc, it may not even be compatible for multi cards :S

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Multimedia  This card used a S3 chip. Oh, those were the days when you had more than 2 major choices for video cards. Those days are gone...

Answer (score 0):

vista drivers work with windows7. update from device manager and point to extracted drivers adn inf files etc. worked for me. matrox mystique 2 meg running 1280 1024. device manager shows matrox card.. but also error. besides error it works fine. drivers came from matrox web site. 2003 year.

Answer (score -1):

There is close to 0% chance there are going to be drivers out there that will work with that card under windows 7. I know it fits in the computer, but there are no official diamond stealth 2500 video card drivers for windows 7. I can't even find reference to it on diamond's site.

It is before Diamond went to all ATI cards even. The only chance is if someone attempted to make their own drivers, which I hardly believe anyone would take the time to make them for a card that old.