# Optiplex 760 + Legacy Rage XL PCI card + Windows 7 x64 = startup issues...?

Tags: boot, pci

When this card is in the system, I get no beeps, no display, no "POST" things occurring...
It's obviously a legacy / old card from year 2000 so not sure if it's bad or what.
I know I've used it in several older servers and things but it's one I've had lying around.

Any ideas of things I can try?
Is this system not compatible with this PCI card?
Is there a legacy hardware setting in BIOS that I'm overlooking?

Please advise.

UPDATE: (updated the title to include windows 7 x64)
Well, I got the system to boot... I had to toggle a setting in BIOS.
Now Windows is saying the device cannot start.
It's assigning the Standard VGA Adapter driver (of course) and when I install the device driver it's throwing an error.  Here is a screenshot
[image]

And here is what the card looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: silly question (on my part, not yours), but any reason you can't use onboard video? Its likely to be better than a 12 year old card. I vaguely remember there's an option to select between primary video cards in some systems as well, but that was AGP vs internal on VERY old computers

Comment: try another pci slot if there is one.

Comment: I'm sorry, using a PCI-E X16 Graphics card for dual displays.  Trying to add this for a basic 3rd display to handle another VGA.

Can't use the integrated due to the PCI-E detection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've found the issue.
The answer is located in this question:
[Second video card (PCI) under Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/27684/second-video-card-pci-under-windows-7)

I'm sorry I missed this originally...
Disappointing I most likely won't get this working.

I wish Windows 7 was more informative in this department... :-\

I'm leaning toward looking at USB Dongle VGA adapters.